# C++ program for PC keyboard release event

Tags: c++, ascii, keyboard-events

I'm writing C++ code to control an User interface file. The purpose is to adjust the FPS (frame per second) of the UI after pressing the button.
Press button 1: Adjust UI to run at a low FPS.
Press button 0: Adjust UI back to run at the original FPS.
Currently, my program can work at low FPS if I press the button 1 and hold. If I press and release immediately, UI will not run at low FPS anymore. I want to make FPS being fixed at the value after pressed and released keyboard button without having to hold it.

Please tell me the way to modify my code to get my expected result.

Below is my brief code:

```
double ti = FPS.Tick(); // original FPS
if(Inp.Key[0] == 1)
{
  ti = FPS.Tick();
  do
  {
    ti = FPS.Tick();
  }while(Inp.Key[0] != 1);
}

else if(Inp.Key[1] == 1)
{
  ti = 0.001;
  do
  {
    ti = 0.001;
  }while(Inp.Key[1] != 1);
}

UI.Run(ti); // execute UI at the adjusted FPS.
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen from assigning the value 0.001 to a double over and over again?

Comment: What environment, or what library, are you using to measure keyboard events? Standard C++ doesn't even know that there is a keyboard.

Comment: I'm running program in Visual Studio 2017. My company has a library developed by the CTO but they didn't explain to me the details of that library. Then, I tried another method of using include <conio.h> to to getch() in while(1). But the UI can't display if I add while(1) to that function.
I think the point is logic, not about the library. You can see Inp.Key[0] as char '0' defined  based on ascii code.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean release key on foreground app then use local hook. see `SetWindowsHookEx` on msdn . you need `NULL` for `HINSTANCE` means no dll